# requirement to directly call sql stored procedure from salesforce

Tags: dbamp

I have a requirement to directly call sql stored procedure from salesforce but those stored procedure are not exposed as a service. I found a tool called DBAmp which states it can be achieved but is there any other way by which we can achieve this or is there anyone who has work on dbamp before.

https://forceamp.com/

Comment: You can call external database's SQL using [lightning connect](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning_connect/lightning_connect_introduction)

Comment: @PranayJaiswal can we call stored procedure written in other database using lightning/salesforce connect?